# Rivers of London short about Magical Signature

Tags: story-identification, rivers-of-london

I'm trying to find a super short story set in the *Rivers of London* universe.

In it the German magic cop Winter interviews the American, Stephen Higgins, associated with the New York Librarians from *False Value*. They talk about Peter Grant, specifically his magical technique and how he appears to pick up on the technique and signature of people he interacts with.

This was a self contained very short story, similar in length to the moments included in the *Tales from the Folly* collection. Which is where I initially assumed this was from.

I can't find where I read this and it's getting quite frustrating.

Comment: Is this fanfic or something canon, like this; https://www.amazon.com/Tales-Folly-Rivers-London-Collection/dp/1625675097

Comment: "Stephen something" is Stephen Higgins?

Comment: The only Rivers of London story I remember set in Germany is “The October Man”. Im sure the cop is called Winters. I can’t definitely confirm that personally as I don’t have the book to hand at the minute.

Comment: I'm pretty confident it's written by Ben Aaronovitch as I don't recall ever reading any Rivers of London fan fiction.

Comment: Equally I don't think it is a full book. But I can't find it in Tales from the Folly myself. And it was super short similar in length to the moments in TftF

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is from Moment 8 - *Peter's Signare* posted to the newsletter

Listing on Follypedia: [https://follypedia.fandom.com/wiki/Moment_eight_—_Peter’s_Signare](https://follypedia.fandom.com/wiki/Moment_eight_%E2%80%94_Peter%E2%80%99s_Signare)

> In a report to Tobias Winter, Regierungsoberinspektor Gunter Gebauer
> details his interview with Stephen in New York, sometime in March
> 2016, concerning the Librarian’s recent encounter with Peter Grant in
> London. Stephen tells of Peter’s Signare, which in his view is unique
> in the world. It has the “tick-tock” of Nightingale but “then it goes
> all over the place”, “like laughing like, like I don’t know - joy.
> Like it’s the most fun he’s ever had and it’s full of extraneous
> noise. Bits of music, the smell of chocolate, that cathedral with the
> dome, running water. Like he’s a kid in a pirate suit who’s been given
> a real pirate ship”.

The whole story is archived and can be read at [Happy Halloween from Rivers of London HQ!](https://us19.campaign-archive.com/?u=4ca47cfd34823a647fa492499&id=43de501401)

Comment: A big "thank you" from me to you (and the OP for raising the question) - somehow I missed the newsletter that had this Moment in it (gmail must have spamhammered it for some reason). Without the two of you I'd have missed this completely.